# How to install the additional module pg_trgm

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.3, installation, postgresql-extensions

I just want to know how to install the [module `pg_tgrm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) as used in the trigram indexing scheme that allows you to do [*un-anchored search patterns*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187658/2639) on an index.

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%';
```

Comment: I cleaned up this question, because it's a good question but has nothing to do with PostGIS or any of that stuff.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`pg_trgm` is an extension, so:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

If you get the following error

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file ".../extension/pg_trgm.control":
> No such file or directory"

then you need to install the module for your operating system. For example:

- Ubuntu/Debian:

  ```
    sudo apt install postgresql-contrib
  ```
- Redhat/Centos

  ```
    sudo dnf install postgresql12-contrib
  ```
- Fedora

  ```
    sudo dnf install postgresql-contrib
  ```
- FreeBSD

  ```
    sudo pkg install postgresql12-contrib
  ```

Of course, "12" can be replaced with whatever version number is appropriate.

Comment: I experienced on MaxOSX following: 

if you install postgresql using conda/pip, then there seems to be no way to install the postgresql-contrib module;

however, if you install postgresql using Homebrew, then this module is automatically installed.

Answer (score 15):

1) Log into postgres

`psql -U <DB_USERNAME>`

2) After you are connected, switch to the DB you want to install the extension for:

`\c <DB_NAME>`

3) Then install the extension as answered previously:

`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`

Installing the extension initially gave me issues because I was not doing step 2.  I thought the installation was a global thing but it seems its **per DB**

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of [@Jendrusk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165301/22336) for :

- CentOs system you can also use

```
yum install postgresql-contrib
```