# What is it called when you search the middle of a string instead of the beginning?

Tags: terminology, regex, string-searching

I am trying to polish up my vocabulary to better communicate with my fellow developers. We have several places in the site where we are debating if we should search for a string from the beginning `'running%'` vs anywhere in the string `'%running%`.

I have been calling the middle search *"fuzzy"* which I realize is incorrect as fuzzy means changing the form of the word "run", "runing" [sic], "runed" [sic].

**What is the correct terminology for searching the beginning of a string and searching the middle of a string?**

Comment: I have worked at places that used "Begins with" vs "Contains" to differentiate between those two options.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's called an *"un-anchored search pattern"*, and it looks like this in SQL.

```
foo LIKE '%bar%'
```

If you lack a `%` on either side, it is said that the search pattern *anchors* to the start or end of the string respectively. This lingo comes from the regex world.

```
foo LIKE 'bar%'
```

You would say, *"the search pattern `bar%` anchored to the start of the string*".

For comparison, a PCRE is anchored with `^` or `$` tokens and it looks like `^bar` or `bar$`. PCREs require explicit anchoring with tokens, whereas SQL `LIKE` statements are implicitly anchored and require explicit `%` to create an *"un-anchored search pattern"*.

As a side note, you can index these types of expressions with trigrams using something like [`pg_trgm` in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/205529/2639)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind to me is "un-[Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)."  Searching for a specific string, or the first part of a string, in an indexed field allows you to seek.  If your search starts with a wildcard, the RDBMS will have to scan the whole index, because values which meet your search predicate could appear anywhere in the set of values.

Consider looking in a telephone book (if you're old enough to remember those...).  You can easily find people who's last names start with "Dan:" you thumb to the Ds, flip forward to the DAs, and the DAN-somethings will be all together.  If you wanted to find people who's last names include the string "ANIEL," you would have to read every page (scan the table).

Comment: "RDBMS will have to scan the whole index" that's so not true. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html

Comment: I think unsargable might be a more general term than is being looked for here as it covers a number of other cases (searching the result of a function performed on a column, for example).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really your question, but your example of fuzzy is imprecise.

- Fuzzy is the opposite of *sharp, binary*, meaning you can have a
  percentage of match, for instance a fuzzy search for `'run'` at
  precision .5 will include 'ran', 'rud', and a lot of other words. SQL does *not* support fuzzy
  search, you need additional systems like Lucene.
- A *wildcard* search will for `'run%'` will always include
  'runing' and 'runed', and you can distinguish the *begins with* and *contains* (`'%run%'` to include 'outrunning') as @[Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky) suggests
- However if you want to find *whole words*, for
  instance in text blocks, you would need to indicate the preceeding or
  trailing whitespace `' run '` (or `' run% '` to include partial matches such as 'bla bla runing bla' and 'bla runed bla bla').