# Indexing the condition lower(f) LIKE '%foo%'

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-extensions

How do I index the following statement with an [un-anchored search pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187658/2639)

```
SELECT somefield
FROM sometable 
WHERE lower(somefield2) like '%foo%';
```

Some rows have more than 2k bytes.

Comment: You had a bunch of stuff in the question that was not relevant to what you were looking for, I cropped it out. Sometimes a simple question just needs to be phrased simply, welcome to [dba.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length aside, a btree index would not help that query. You could create a hash index but that would also only help if the query wants an exact match for the whole column. not for a substring pattern. To do what you want first, add the `pg_trgm` extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Then create a trigram index:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON sometable
  USING GIN (somefield2 gin_trgm_ops); -- can also be GIST
```

A trigram index can help find matches for SQL's `LIKE` and `ILIKE` and regex patterns.

For more information see the docs on [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html)