# SQL search for a pattern in the middle of a string (infix search) without full table scan

Tags: full-text-search, string-searching, scan

With SQL, I need to select rows which have a pattern like `%hello%` (i.e. `<anything>hello<anything>`) in a column, with potentially 100 millions of rows or more.

In the answer [Infix search in MySQL with an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121624/infix-search-in-mysql-search-with-pattern-in-the-middle-with-an-index/76121736#76121736), it is said that:

- an index won't help
- even an *FTS index* won't help either

Question: **are there RDBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL) that have features that can speed up queries like**

```
select * from t where key like "%hello%"
```

**and avoid a full table scan?**

With specific data structures (tries, etc.), or bigrams, trigrams, etc.

TL;DR: I have a MySQL InnoDB like this:

```
create table t (id int primary key auto_increment, 
                key varchar(200), value varchar(200));
create index key_index on t(key) using BTREE;
create index value_index on t(value) using BTREE;
```

and I would like to do this without a full table scan:

```
select * from t where key like "%hello%"
```

Notes:

- the strings are not words separated by spaces. Columns `key` and `value` have typically 10 to 50 characters, with no spaces. They can be `abcdefhelloworldblablabla`.
- see also [What is it called when you search the middle of a string instead of the beginning?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187658/what-is-it-called-when-you-search-the-middle-of-a-string-instead-of-the-beginnin)

Comment: There are database systems meant for tokenizing words for efficient *contains* type of searching, like Elasticsearch. But it's unclear if your question is looking for the proper database suggestion for this use case, or a solution to how to do it with your existing database system, MySQL?

Comment: Possibly a trigram index is what you are looking for. There are various ways to implement one.

Comment: @Charlieface Do some RDBMS like MySQL or PostgreSQL or another include this as an out-of-the-box feature? e.g. `CREATE INDEX ON t(key) option=trigram;`. Feel free to post an answer with the trigram solution, it would be interesting!

Comment: @J.D. If possible I'll continue with MySQL, but since it's the start of my project, I can easily switch to PostgreSQL or another.

Comment: Postgres does support this. PaulWhite has an article on how to implement this yourself in SQL Server using triggers, see https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search